# Combine CSS mediaqueries conditions

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm looking for a way to combine several CSS mediaquery conditions.
I want to apply certain rules when

a) the max-width is 480 OR
b) the max-width is 800 given the orientation of the device is landscape

Is it possible to put that in one statement? I could obviously make two rules and give them both the same CSS stuff, but that's not very efficient

Thanks in advance

edit: please see additional comment below

Comment: When you set `max-width` to `800`, the first statement `max-width: 480px` would be useless.

Comment: Makes sense... What I'm trying to achieve is, is that the rule gets applied on mobile devices with a width of max 800, but not on computer screens with a width of 800. It should apply ONLY when a) mobile screen max 800 AND b) desktop screen max 480

Comment: You have to copy it and put it in both manually

Comment: The problem here is that even desktop browsers honor the `orientation` media feature. You can't reliably distinguish a mobile browser from a desktop browser with a media query.

Comment: @BoltClock: True, I just found that out by using two separate rules. Hmm, I just think that a Samsung S2 landscape (width 800) needs different layouts than a computer screen with 800. But I guess the latter is unrealistic anyways nowadays, so I might as well just ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that most computer monitors nowadays will have a wider resolution, you could use `max-device-width` to distinguish mobiles from desktops:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation:landscape), screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

Note that the queries are separated by comma which is equivalent to a logical "OR" operator

Comment: Thanks. I decided to differentiate a little bit between the 480 and the 800 rules so I used separate ones, but in case I need to combine them, I'll use this. Thank you :)